# Return empty when using await?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Which is correct way to return nothing when using await?

Usage:

```
exports.run = async => {
    try {
        await update(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Function:

```
function update() {
    if (data) {
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    }

    // does not need to be rejected.
    return; //Is this correct?
    return Promise.resolve(); //Is this correct?
}
```

Comment: `return` and `return Promise.resolve()` will work identically for an async function

Comment: It doesn't matter WRT `await`. It can handle both Promises and other values. However if a function returns a Promise it is best to make it always return a Promise (it's a good idea in general to always return the same data type from a function). If you sometimes return a Promise and sometimes `undefined`, then someone might call the function and try to use `.then` on the result which will throw an error if it is `undefined`.

Comment: You can either make the function `async` and leave off the return statement or have an empty return statement, or you can use `return Promise.resolve( );` whether or not you make it async.

Comment: In my opinion the nicest option is to leave out the return statement and just make the function `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to not use `return` statement at all, so that the returned promise resolves with `undefined` at the end of the function:

```
async function update() {
    if (data) 
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
}
```

But you can spell it out explicitly as well, and when you return a `Promise.resolve(…)` then you don't need to mark the function as `async`:

```
async function update() {
    if (data) 
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    return;
}
async function update() {
    if (data) 
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    return undefined;
}
function update() {
    if (data) 
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    return Promise.resolve();
}
function update() {
    if (data) 
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
async function update() {
    return data ? updateRecord(data).promise() : undefined;
}
function update() {
    return data ? updateRecord(data).promise() : Promise.resolve();
}
function update() {
    return data ? updateRecord(data).promise() : Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

They all achieve the same. Use the simplest and most readable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `update()` isn't `async`, return `Promise.resolve()` for "nothing". That way the signature (in TypeScript syntax for convenience) of the function will be `(...) => Promise`, not `(...) => Promise | undefined`.

You can also make the function `async`, in which case returning `undefined` will be wrapped into a promise internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can just leave out any additional explicit returns- just add the async keyword to the function and it will execute properly

```
async function update() {
    if (data) {
        return updateRecord(data).promise();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will reject via promise go to catch block - I got try in the main block?

Comment: Yes, rejected promises and errors thrown will be caught in the catch block of your main try/catch block @user88432